# Runtime resizing row height in TableLayoutPanel by mouse

Tags: c#, winforms

There is a Form with TableLayoutPanel. TableLayoutPanel contains some controls. They resizing normally. But I want to change their ratio in run-time. Same way as in designer.

Comment: Check your form.Designer.cs file there you will get everything...

Comment: You describe a task instead of asking a question.  Good luck with it, you'll get no help whatsoever from TLP.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of changing the 1st row to 50% at runtime:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[0] = new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50);
```

And 1st column similarly:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles[0] = new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50);
```

For the user to control it try and design your Form to use a [SplitterPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitterpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, which has built-in drag resizing.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using SplitterPanel without TableLayoutPanel.